# CoordinatorLayout custom behavior at right of Toolbar with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Based on this tutorial, https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample,I am trying to create an application which have a circle image that scrolls up to the Right of Toolbar and when scrolling down goes to the middle of the expanded AppBarLayout.

How to make it move to right of Toolbar with above mentiond behaviour and animation.

[image]

Comment: Image will be animated to right till it reaches toolbar and again animated to come at center . I do not get any reply on this. Any kind of help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

[AppBarTranslateScaleBehavior](https://github.com/RanyAlbegWein/AppBarTranslateScaleBehavior) will help you achieve such a behavior.